# Flexbox and does not work nth-child(n)

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I have issue with background for element `article`. I use `:nth-child(n)`, but they do not work correctly at my localhost. When I same code place to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f43mLh3o/) all is ok.

Code at my local is following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>:: Nove pokusy s Yablkem ::</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ath/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/yablko.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <article>Jsem ve středě?</article>
    <article>Všichni co se moc ptají se nic nedozví...</article>
    <article>Marmelada</article>
    <article>Sýrové kuličky || Menu</article>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS (yablko.css)

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  background: orange;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: baseline;

  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

article {
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: #336dd1;
  border-radius: .8em;
  margin: 5px;
}
article:nth-child(1) { background: #888; }
article:nth-child(2) { background: #ccd; }
article:nth-child(3) { background: #333; font-size: 10px; }
article:nth-child(4) { background: #aaa; font-size: 30px; }
```

Image from local (bad result): [image]
Image from jsfiddle (ok result): [image]

Can I ask for help? Thanks

Comment: those two images are completely different. my bet, you changed the css on your local computer and forgot to reload it using Ctrl+R in your browser.

Comment: No, no. I watch my css file using gulp. Change will happen automatically.

Comment: are you sure the html/css are the same ones in both cases? can you replicate the issue anywhere were we can actually see it? also, did you actually run the code in a browser? some previewers/html editors do not support those selectors and will not preview them.

Comment: Now when I html and css file placed to server (http://www.ondrej-vasko.cz/html/yablko.html) is all ok. Is it strange that sublime text 3 with gulp does not support some selectors.

Comment: `:nth-child` is a css3 selector. some editors dont support css3 preview yet.